# The derivatives of a diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry

I read this:

> Let $F_t^s:\Omega_s \to \Omega_t$ be a diffeomorphism between hypersurfaces. Let $\text{det}D_{\Omega_s}F_t^s(\cdot)$ be the Jacobian of the matrix representation of $D_{\Omega_s}F_t^s(\cdot)$ with respect to the orthogonal basis of the respective tangent space.

My question is, what exactly is $D_{\Omega_s}F_t^s(\cdot)$? Why should it not be just the usual matrix of partial derivatives of the components of $F_t^s$? And what is meant by "with respect to the orthogonal basis...". I understand there is a tangent space associated to each point in the surface $\Omega_s$, which is a vector space, so it has a basis. But that's about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D_{\Omega_s}F_t^s(\cdot)$ means the differential of $F_t^s$, which is the induced linear map between tangent spaces. We can always choose basis from the two tangent spaces, and represent this linear map, as a matrix.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an example?

Comment: Not sure which kind of examples you are asking, and not sure I understood the original post clearly or not. But let me try to give an example: Let $\Omega_t$ be spheres of radius t, centered at the origin O, in $R^3$. And define $F_t^s$ as $F(x,y,z)=t(x,y,z)/s$, where $x^2+y^2+z^2=s^2$. Choose a point p=(x,y,z), the linear map induced in the tangent planes will map a tangent vector (a,b,c) at p to a tangent vector t(a,b,c)/s at tp/s, and the determinant of this map will be $t^2/s^2$.

Comment: Thank you! So I guess the first element (row 1 column 1) of the matrix $D_{\Omega_s}F_t^s$ in your example would be $\frac{t}{s}.$ This is my point of confusion: how did the orthogonal basis come into play here? In forming the matrix $D_{\Omega_s}F_t^s$ how am I using the basis?

Comment: A linear map is independent of its representation with respect to a specific basis. So you can any orthogonal basis as you want. And the resulting matrix will have different forms with different chosen basis.